# Problem when trying to indent text using function /item

Tags: indentation

I'm trying to use command `\item` to indent a certain part of text to look like this:

[image]

But it appears like this:

[image]

Can someone tell me what's wrong?

Comment: Looks fine to me! What is the intended outcome?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many different ways to achieve the desired result (e.g. use a `\parbox[t]{..}{..}` for the parts to be aligned). But I would suggest to use an ordinary tabular instead of the description environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
   \begin{tabular}{ll}
   \large \textbf{Keywords:} & Nonlinear Dynamics \\
                             & Isogeometric Analysis\\
                             & Porosity-dependent properties\\
                             & Functionally graded materials\\
                             & Non-classical continuum elasticity
   \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. Please check my answer below as then I get another problem using that function.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
% indentprob.tex  SE 599715
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
   \begin{description}
     \item[\large Key Words:] \mbox{} \\ % move to next line
Nonlinear Dynamics \\
Isogeometric Analysis\\
Porosity-dependent properties\\
Functionally graded materials\\
Non-classical continuum elasticity
   \end{description}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help, but thats not my desired output. I tried to use your solution in conjunction with the `&` character before each argument but apparently it only works with the `\begin{tabular}` function proposed in **Niko**'s solution.

Comment: I also tried not using the line skip command `\\ ` after the `mbox[]` function but still no success.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for late reply as I don't use Stack Overflow much nor have notification on my e-mail, but meanwhile I implemented the solution **Niko** suggested, but than I get another error :/

This is what happens:

[image]

It's like it gets some kind of indentation. I tried to use command `\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}` at the beginning of the document and changing justification position from `ll` for another options like `cc` or `rl` but got the same output. Also tried to use the `\large` command inside the brackets insted of outside, but still no difference. :/

Is there anything else I can do?

Comment: Hi Joao, could you provide a minimal working example code (MWE), where the problem occurs? You could use my answer code and extent it with your settings until the error occurs. Without that it's hard to say what causes the issue.